# Magento 2.2.7 - Issue With Configurable Product Details Page having more than 20 associated products - MageMojo, Nginx

Tags: configurable-product, product-view, frontend-error, magento2.2.7

- We are receiving this error on opening a configurable product in the frontend.
- The configurable product having 20+ associated products. The issue is not there with other products having less number of associated products.
- But It started happening after moving to MageMojo and upgrading Magento to 2.2.7. The issue is not there with our old development server and with Magento 2.1.8.
- We tried contacting MageMojo support but they denied saying that there is no issue with the server.

Please suggest a way to debug as this error seems to be very generic
   and we don't have any other details at this moment.

**Error:**

> *396 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xx.xxx.xxx, server: example.mojostratus.io, request: "GET url-of-product-page.html HTTP/1.1",$ host: "example.mojostratus.io"

Comment: this appears to be timeout related. are you use a CDN? if so, try bypassing it.

Comment: There is no CDN.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/147292)